# Jest Setup and CleanUp

Tags: testing, jestjs, e2e-testing, puppeteer

Is it possible to do some tasks **only once** before all test suites and do the clean up once after all the test suites have completed?

The scenario is I want to create a user before any of the test suites are executed and once all the test suites complete executing then I want to clear all the trace of that user. How can I achieve that using jest and puppeteer?

I tried globalSetup globalTeardown and setupTestFrameworkScriptFile but they all run once before each test suites.

Comment: I'm setting up puppeteer in `globalSetup` and destroying it in `globalTeardown` only once per all tests. I only follow this guides: https://github.com/xfumihiro/jest-puppeteer-example

Comment: You're tagging the wrong person. I just edited your question. Didn't answer or comment :)